# Conditional trigger start new row on another table with auto increment

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a quotes table and a jobs table in a MySQL database. I want to automatically create a job number when I change the quote disposition to PO obtained. The disposition field in an enum so their will be no variance.

The JobNum field is auto-incremented so I felt inserting the bid number into the table would auto generate a new row and thus a job number.

This is the script I was playing with.

> DELIMITER $$
>
> CREATE
>       TRIGGER `create_job` AFTER UPDATE
>       ON `Quotes`
>       FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
>       IF `Quotes.QuoteDispo` = `PO obtained`
>       INSERT INTO `Jobs` (`BidNum`)
>       SELECT `BidNum`
>       FROM `enjouede_delham`.`Quotes`
>
> ```
> END$$
> ```
>
> DELIMITER ;

I would also like to create a pop-up warning prior to the action in case of entry error. Is this possible with PHP or must I use JavaScript? I am using PHPRunner to create the data entry forms but can insert custom scripts for functionality.

Comment: Attempted this


DELIMITER $$

CREATE

    TRIGGER `Job_Create` AFTER UPDATE
    ON `Quotes`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    
      IF `Quotes`.`QuoteDispo` IS `PO obtained`

     INSERT INTO `Jobs` (BidNum, ClientNum)
       SELECT GETDATE(), BidNum, ClientNum, 
       FROM UPDATE ROW
    END$$

DELIMITER ;